# TinyMCE : How activate Spell Checker permanently

Tags: javascript, parameters, tinymce

In TinyMCE we must manually activate the Spell Checker via a toolbar button when we want to correct words. How can I have this button activated all the time ?

Thanks

Comment: You mean this? https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/spelling/#browser_spellcheck

Comment: There are multiple spell checker options available for TinyMCE.  Are you using the browser_spellcheck option?  Are you using the open source Spell Checker plugin?   Are you using the commercial Spell Checker Pro plugin?  The answer will vary based on how you have setup spell checking.

Comment: I use open source Spell Checker plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The open source Spell Checker plugin has no documented way to do what you want.  You could certainly modify the plugin code to start with spelling enabled as opposed to its current default.

Answer (score 1):

You can trigger the spellchecker plugin on TinyMCE 5 with

```
instance.execCommand('mceSpellCheck', {});
```